# how to cast context for custom Application class

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I am developing the logic to check whether my app is in foreground with custom Application class.  When I try to cast the class in MyFirebaseMessagingService.java, the error comes out.  The code is shown below.

```
boolean isForeground = ((MyAppStatus)getApplication()).isForeground();
```

Also, I tried with codes like below.

```
boolean isForeground = MyAppStatus.get(getApplicationContext).isForeground();
```

and

```
boolean isForeground = MyAppStatus.get(getApplication).isForeground();
```

But, I encountered the same cast error.

The code of the custom Application class is shown below.

```
public class MyAppStatus extends Application {
    private AppStatus mAppStatus = AppStatus.FOREGROUND;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new MyActivityLifecycleCallbacks());
    }

    public static MyAppStatus get(Context context) {
        return (MyAppStatus)context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    public AppStatus getAppStatus() {
        return mAppStatus;
    }

    // check if app is foreground
    public boolean isForeground() {
        return mAppStatus.ordinal() > AppStatus.BACKGROUND.ordinal();
    }

    public enum AppStatus {
        BACKGROUND,                // app is background
        RETURNED_TO_FOREGROUND,    // app returned to foreground(or first launch)
        FOREGROUND;                // app is foreground
    }
```

The error is like below.

```
12-10 22:26:59.256 32544-32633/com.forwards.android.goodhus E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: pool-2-thread-1
                                                                          Process: com.XXXXXX.android.XXXXXX, PID: 32544
                                                                          java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to com.XXXXXX.android.XXXXXX.common.utils.MyAppStatus
                                                                              at com.XXXXXX.android.XXXXXX.common.fcm.MyFirebaseMessagingService.sendToNotificationCenter(MyFirebaseMessagingService.java:187)
```

Some with great experience would be great help.
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to register your `MyAppStatus` class in manifest `application` tag, like

```
 <application
        android:name=".MyAppStatus"
```

Comment: Yes, it worked.  Thanks a lot.  Could you let me know how I can mark this answer as the correct answer?

Comment: @ShawnKang i am glad that i could help , happy coding

Comment: Yes, I did.  It's the very first question that I accepted.  Thanks a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `getApplicationContext()` instead:

```
boolean isForeground = ((MyAppStatus)getApplicationContext()).isForeground();
```

And make sure the application is set using `android:name=".MyAppStatus"` in the application tag in the manifest. Otherwise you'll get the wrong object

Comment: i think it's a typo because the error clearly says it's an `android.app.Application` object

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh if you think it's a typo, vote to close instead of answering.

Comment: i mean your initial answer was indicating a typo which has no relation with error but now you have got the idea what the issue is and incorporated my answer , it's fine

Comment: It's not indicating a typo, getApplicationContext is a different way to access it. If getApplication doesn't work, try getApplicationContext. OP's post contains a typo when attempting to retrieve these, and I have no clue if that's by intent, accident or a copy-paste problem. So it's still a valid option

Comment: `So it's still a valid option` then stick to it or if you gonna use already given answer([a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47739510/how-to-cast-context-for-custom-application-class/47739525#comment82439250_47739539) stating a huge possible error) then would be ideal to appreciate the answer (rest is your choice ) :)